# I'm getting a runtime errror 438 when trying to format a column in a spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba

Sheets("Reformatted").Column("F").NumberFormat = "$#,##0.000"

Comment: should be Columns not Column

Comment: thank you sooooooooooo much, can't believe I missed that simple little issue

Answer (score 0):

To better debug a complex expression, break it into smaller parts.  In your case:

```
Set sh = Sheets("Reformatted")
Set rg = sh.Column("F")
Let rg.NumberFormat = "$#,##0.000"
```

Broken into multiple statements, you can step using the debugger, and figure out exactly which piece part of the larger statement is causing the problem.  Since the error happens on the Column statement, you can deduce that the error message is referring to `Column`.